# Allocating non-default hugepages with mmap or shmget on linux x86-64

Tags: linux, huge-pages

UPDATE: I switched the default hugepagesize to 2MB and rebooted to confirm that it was always the non-default size that failed, and now I can allocate from both pools. I am confused, but possibly making progress.

I have been trying to get shmget and mmap to allocate from the non-default hugepage pool without success on kernel 4.13.0-32-generic. I have configured both 2M and 1G hugepages. With the 1G page as the default size this call will succeed:

`addr = mmap(0, byteAmount, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_HUGETLB|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_HUGE_1GB, -1, 0);`

but this will fail with `Cannot allocate memory`:

`addr = mmap(0, byteAmount, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_HUGETLB|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_HUGE_2MB, -1, 0);`

hugeadm --explain output:

```
Total System Memory: 32004 MB

Mount Point          Options
/dev/hugepages       rw,relatime,pagesize=1024M
/dev/hugepages2MB    rw,relatime,pagesize=2M

Huge page pools:
      Size  Minimum  Current  Maximum  Default
   2097152     1024     1024     1024         
1073741824        1        1        1        *

Huge page sizes with configured pools:
2097152
1073741824

The /proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes of 67584 is too small. To maximiuse efficiency
of fragmentation avoidance, there should be at least one huge page free per zone
in the system which minimally requires a min_free_kbytes value of 57671680

A /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax value of 6442450944 bytes may be sub-optimal. To maximise
shared memory usage, this should be set to the size of the largest shared memory
segment size you want to be able to use. Alternatively, set it to a size matching
the maximum possible allocation size of all huge pages. This can be done
automatically, using the --set-recommended-shmmax option.

The recommended shmmax for your currently allocated huge pages is 3221225472 bytes.
To make shmmax settings persistent, add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf:
  kernel.shmmax = 3221225472
hugeadm:WARNING: There is no swap space configured, resizing hugepage pool may fail
hugeadm:WARNING: Use --add-temp-swap option to temporarily add swap during the resize

To make your hugetlb_shm_group settings persistent, add the following line to /etc/sysctl.conf:
  vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0

Note: Permanent swap space should be preferred when dynamic huge page pools are used.
```

The objective is to be able to use a combination of both 2MB and 1GB pages to maximise TLB hitrates. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I confirmed that both the mmap and shmget calls are now working to allocate memory from both the 2M and 1G hugepage pools. It looks like the hugepage system had somehow got into a bad state and a reboot was needed to fix it. Possibly this was caused by me changing the size of the 1G pool dynamically by writing to `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages`

Sorry for the noise!